# Should home theater / non-studio or production related equipment questions be on topic?

Tags: discussion

These questions were not on topic on AVP and it sounds like they were not present on SSD either.  Do we have any interest in addressing the home theater/personal listening arenas or do we want to limit equipment questions to those that relate to sound production and design?

Answer (score 9):

I agree, home theater and consumer/prosumer isn't the target demographic of SSD/SDSE.  Other questions about amps, preamps, recorders, mics, plugins, software, libraries, sound books, etx are all fair game here.

The kinds of conusmer/prosumer questions dilute the energy/focus that this forums has been all about.

Music questions don't belong here either.  UNLESS they are music as it related to one of the sound disciplines (example: music editor, scoring for film/tv, stems/splits/deliverables, music re-record mixing and music mixing in general as it relates to DM&E, etc).

Comment: Good point about the music stuff as well.

Comment: Could the site offer an alternative place to post such questions?

Comment: I think the descriptions of the site should be updated to make this clear. I tried to look carefully but did not understand this distinction before asking a question that turned out to be off-topic.

Answer (score 7):

Based on the fact it appears to have been off topic on both AVP and SSD, it seems like it should still be off topic here.  For more information, you can see the original reasoning from AVP [here](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204/are-non-production-video-and-audio-questions-on-topic-here).

Answer (score 3):

There are certain topics related to home theater and audio that overlap with professional recording, such as acoustical room treatments--absorbers, diffusers, etc.  These should be accepted.

[Designing a diffuser to direct reflections to side walls](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/41851/designing-a-diffuser-to-direct-reflections-to-side-walls)

[Front acoustic absorber placement with in-wall speakers](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/41693/front-acoustic-absorber-placement-with-in-wall-speakers?rq=1)

Comment: Yeah, I agree with this as long as it is truly directly dual-relevant.  Often, it is then also preferable to generalize the question so it can be more generally useful.  Where I think it gets tricky is when it's something that is semi-related, but the principles involved differ greatly from consumer approaches and professional.  I think the key is that it needs to be directly relevant to production, even if it is also relevant to home theater.  I don't think the context of the question matters as long as that direct relevance is still there.