# Headphone Recommendations

Tags: support, topic-scope

I've got a question related to headphone recommendations. For example, *which are the best over-ear, closed back & wired headphones that doesn't require an amp under $100 for movies?*

Can I ask about it here? Is it on topic?

Comment: If this is only for watching movie, then I'm afraid it's [off-topic](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82). However, it might be on-topic on [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/headphones), but **ensure you have followed [their guidance on asking a good request](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/205)**

Comment: @AndrewT. Thank you. Let me check that.

Comment: Asked [there](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10410/headphone-recommendations-for-watching-movies). @AndrewT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for checking. This would, unfortunately, be completely off topic for this site as we only deal with production related questions and even for production usage, this would be a shopping question.  We could answer about what to look for in headphones for a professional use, but specific product recommendations isn't a good fit for the site in addition to not covering any non-production audio.